# getting data from apex_item.text

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Good day,

I am trying to capture date from a apex_item.text but its not working

my classic report table is

```
SELECT apex_item.checkbox2(1,productID,'class=indCheck')
     
   || apex_item.hidden(2,productname)
     || apex_item.hidden(3, productcode)
    || apex_item.hidden(5,amount)

       as  "SELECT",

       PRODUCTID,
       PRODUCTCODE,
       PRODUCTNAME,
       PRODUCTDESC,
       CATEGORYCODE,
       SERIALNUMBER,
       UNITPRICE,
       REORDERLEVEL,
       DISCONTINUED,
       UNITSINHAND,
       STATUS,
       LOCATION,
       LOCATIONDESCRIPTION,
        apex_item.text (20,amount) as amount
  from PRODUCTS
```

my pl/sql consist of

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count loop

     if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then  
 
    
       insert into pending
         (products,employeename,department,dates  ,amount      
       
         )
         values
         (apex_application.g_f02(idx),:app_user,:app_user,
        sysdate,apex_application.g_f05(idx));
         
          
    
          
        
                  
  end if ;
  end loop;

end;
```

everything is being captured except the  `apex_item.text (20,amount) as amount` which is being reference with `apex_application.g_f05(idx)`

Answer (score 1):

I did use the same code as you are using and it worked fine.

See my understanding.

Table 1:

```
DROP TABLE ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP
(
  EMPNO   NUMBER,
  ENAME   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  SAL     NUMBER,
  LOC     VARCHAR2(22 BYTE),
  DEPT    VARCHAR2(22 BYTE),
  ACTIVE  VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)                      DEFAULT 'N'
);

Sample data


SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP
   (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, LOC, DEPT, 
    ACTIVE)
 Values
   (1, 'Sahay', 1000, 'Delhi', 'SOFTWARE', 
    'N');
Insert into ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP
   (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, LOC, DEPT, 
    ACTIVE)
 Values
   (4, 'TEst', 555, 'Noida', 'DBA', 
    'N');
Insert into ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP
   (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, LOC, DEPT, 
    ACTIVE)
 Values
   (7, 'TEst', 555, 'Noida', 'DBA', 
    'N');
Insert into ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP
   (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, LOC, DEPT, 
    ACTIVE)
 Values
   (2, 'Ashish', 1000, 'Gurugram', 'IT2', 
    'N');
COMMIT;
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE ashish_apex_item_issue
(
   empno    NUMBER,
   amount   NUMBER
);
```

Report Query

```
select apex_item.checkbox2(1,empno,'class=indCheck')  || apex_item.hidden(5,sal) as  "SELECT",
EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       apex_item.text (20,SAL) as amount,
       LOC,
       DEPT,
       ACTIVE
  from ASHISH_SAMPLE_EMP
```

Save data Process

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count loop

     if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then  
 
    
       insert into ashish_apex_item_issue
         (empno,amount      
       
         )
         values
         (apex_application.g_f01(idx),apex_application.g_f05(idx));      
  end if ;
  end loop;

end;
```

[image: Process Code]

[image: Report Data]

Please follow the below article

https://roelhartman.blogspot.com/2018/02/apexapplicationgf0x-array-processing-in.html

Comment: The difference between my example and yours is that the 'apex_item.text (20,amount) as amount' field doesnt have a value ,i am entering a value from my classic report so that it could be entered in the pending table from the save process pl/sql